# Using OpenLayers (with OpenStreetMaps) and PostGIS for rendering data acquired from GPS tracking device

Tags: postgis, openlayers-2, gps, geodjango

I am researching and planning to acquire data from GPS device and store them in PostGIS database, then use geodjango to process/work them out and finally chart them on a map with OpenLayers.

Will these technologies be enough for my plan, since I don't want my maps?

I want to use OpenStreetMap and plot my points on an OpenLayers' vector layer.

I also want to implement real time tracking on a map, I'll query the PostGIS database in real-time using AJAX and then recreate objects on a map. I just cannot find any good examples to do this with OpenLayers. Can I use Jquery for this and combine it with OpenLayers since I'm good at using Jquery's AJAX methods.

I am still researching these technologies, but OpenLayers/geodjango/postGIS seems like a great combo for my needs. I found literature for almost everything that I'm interested in these 3, only that I lack the examples of real time charting and refreshing objects on OpenLayers' vector layer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the [rotate features](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/rotate-features.html) OpenLayers example.

Moving a features works in the same way but using [move](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Point-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.Point.move), e.g.:

```
var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Simple Geometry");
// create a point feature
var point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(-110, 45);
pointFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point, null, style_blue);

map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(point.x, point.y), 5);
vectorLayer.addFeatures([pointFeature]);

// move the point one unit up and redraw            
window.setInterval(function() {
    pointFeature.geometry.move(0, map.getResolution() * 1);
    pointFeature.layer.drawFeature(pointFeature);
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 4):

## Temporal Filter Strategy

[Example](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/filter-strategy.html)

Another way to go is using a temporal filter strategy (filter by time). But first you'll need your data exposed in OGC web service form.

Since you're still researching these technologies you might come to realization that it will be beneficial to use something like GeoServer or MapServer in between your PostGIS and OpenLayers. This is so your PostGIS data can be exposed as web services in OGC Standards such as WFS, WMS, etc. OpenLayers can take advantage of this is many ways and you'll be thanking me later.

Once you have your data exposed via a Map Server like GeoServer you'll be able to use the **temporal filter strategy**.