# What is the most efficient way of displaying GPS in real time using OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2

i'm would like to display GPS traces (not only a position) in realtime on OpenLayers. What is the most efficient way to do it? Sending KML or GPX files to browser or sending data via GeoJSON?

br
d

Comment: I think Sending data via GeoJSON will be useful..

Comment: Might be useful http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/javascript/9781849514125/making-web-map-apps/ch11lvl1sec08#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTk3ODE4NDk1MTQxMjUlMkZjaDExbHZsMXNlYzEw  and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20356/using-openlayers-with-openstreetmaps-and-postgis-for-rendering-data-acquired-f

Answer (score 4):

check out this map animation example [SBB Network Simulator](http://simcity.vasile.ch/sbb/). I think that's pretty good for your needs. as @Sunil pointed out that GeoJSON would help you for huge datas. actually i dont think that geojson or kml make problem for you but browser restrictions. all your format which you havee mentioned that data interchangable format for mapping issues which are widely used by gis people.

[image]

i hope it helps you...

Comment: GeoJSON requires less heavy parsing work from the browser than KML or GML. That can make a big difference.

Comment: this is an important point which @underdark have mentioned if you dont want to wrestle with hard coding.

Answer (score 0):

It really doesn't matter, the transport payload will be the same, rendering will have to suffer according with the method you will choose. I would go for straigh rendering via OL and if the trace becomes too complicated, I would simplify it (with Douglas–Peucker algorithm for example)